# DB2 and Linux remote server replication

Tags: linux, database, db2

I'm using DB2 10.5 and SLES 11 SP4.

My Question is, how would I replicate a remote server's db without having to ssh in and manually export/import.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to replicate database depending on the details of the requirement, and your DB2 licences and available skills.  You can have a DB2-client product connect from remote. You can ask your DBA to setup SQL-based replication  (or Q-based replication) between two databases. You can have near real time (or delayed) replication via DB2 HADR if you ask your DBA to set that up. Or you can occasionally take an online-DB2-backup of the source and restore that on a different environment and rollforward to the logs to get a snapshot of the database at a point in time. Talk with your DBA if you have one, or study the documentation of DB2 some more.